# Linux server stops responding, no video output

Tags: linux, nixos

I built a Linux server out of commodity hardware and every now and then it stops responding. I can't ssh in, my docker jobs don't respond, and when I plug in a monitor there is no video output until I press the reset button. It's almost like the server is sleeping, but the power light is still on, the GPU light is still on, and the network activity light is flashing.

Silly realization: I didn't try pressing any keyboard keys or pinging the server.

*Update:* The server is not responding to ping, and pressing keys on the keyboard does not do anything. The server is also using a typical idle wattage.

I haven't seen anything particularly interesting in any logs I've been able to find (most recently `dmesg`), but I don't really know what I'm looking for either. How can I figure out what is going on? I am running nixOS 23.05.3580.5d017a8822e0 (Stoat).

Comment: Not a helpful comment, but  your problem is exemplary as to why most professionals don't DIY server builds from commodity hardware (anymore) and are willing to pay the premium for brand name enterprise servers (and even then quality is not 110% assured but get do somebody to blame and provide warranty). There can be unexpected integration problems and for example the lack of out-of-band-access (like an ILO / iDrac and siblings) can make those extra hard to debug.

Comment: For sure, I’ve learned to go with server-grade hardware for any expansions moving forward.

Comment: Assuming this is for a company, you did take ESD precautions, didn't you? In some companies if you don't, it is instant dismissal, at least, that was the case for one company I worked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wound up being a firmware issue. I upgraded the motherboard’s firmware to the latest version and the server has been running strong ever since!